# Fastai size mismatch on EC2 instance, but not on local machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, fast-ai

I am trying to launch a web app using fastai on AWS EC2 instance, but I am getting a size mismatch error between the checkpoint and the current model.

However, this web app works fine on my local machine using the same files, I have been testing it locally for days and it still does not run into this issue.

Any advice? I thought it was something to do with the package versions but so far I haven't gotten anywhere with that.

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for AWD_LSTM:
    size mismatch for encoder.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([6399, 400]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([6389, 400]).
    size mismatch for encoder_dp.emb.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([6399, 400]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([6389, 400]).
```